# is there a specific payload format for <https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate>?

Tags: python-3.x, api, authentication, python-requests, minecraft

I am currently trying to write code to find out what has changed for the authentication of migrated accounts for Minecraft and this is my code.

```
import requests
from uuid import uuid4

uuid = uuid4().hex   #used as client token

payload = {
    "agent": {
        "name": "Minecraft",
        "version": 1
    },
    "username": "AGmailAccount@gmail.com",
    "password": "APasswordToTheAccount",
    "clientToken": uuid,
    "requestUser": True
}

print(requests.post("https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate", headers = {"content-type":"application/json"}, data = payload))
```

Every time I run it I get a 400 error code, I should be getting an appropriate, non-200 HTTP status code or a JSON-encoded dictionary.

```
my resources are 
<https://wiki.vg/Mojang_API> , 
<https://wiki.vg/Authentication> , 
and the mojangapi library <https://pypi.org/project/mojang-api/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this line instead:

```
print(requests.post("https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate", json=payload))
```

You weren't sending the JSON the right way.

Comment: that helps but now its a 410 error